# xcode 6,launch image, iOS7, iPhon5s iPhone4s

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

The only consolation I take from this is that apparently I am not the only one having difficulty, specifically generating a launch image.  I have googled the issue hundreds of times, consulted the iOS Dev Centre and searched through my rather extensive library of texts on the matter.

How are launch images created in Xcode 6 on an iPhone 5s(iPhone4 s) running iOS 7?

Comment: The simplest way is to click the "use asset catalog" button

Comment: I haven't found good documentation on this either. The Asset Catalog doesn't work -- in Xcode 6, iPad and iPhone app, landscape mode, it only has launch images spots for Retina HD 5.5" (iPhone 6+) and iPad 1x and 2x. Where the heck did the launch images for smaller devices go?!?

Comment: I've noticed that in a brand new project, using the Launch XIB works for all devices. Now if I can just get that to work in an existing/old Xcode project...

Comment: using the launch XIB does not work to me

Answer (score 2):

set Launch Images in project setting page－>general->launch image source

Comment: Your solution for me has worked! My apps runs great on iPhone 4/4s and iPhone 5/5c/5s with iOS 7.1 and runs great on iPhone 4s, iPhone 5/5c/5s and iPhone 6/6+ with iOS 8.1! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because I'm using Xcode 6.1 and my app deployment target is 7.0.

I tried using the asset catalog with my existing images. Doing that gave me this error:

```
/ObfuscatedProjectPath/Images.xcassets: The launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content.
```

My solution was to turn off the asset catalog and use the default names for the images:

- Default@2x.png (iPhone 4/s size is still supported in iOS7)
- Default-568h@2x.png (works for iPhone 5/6/6Plus sizes)